# React native + Jest: Unexpected token '{'

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am currently trying to include Jest into my react-native project.

However, i run into the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` when running jest.

[image: Full error here:]

Here is the package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.6.4",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.3",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
        "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
        "eslint": "^6.6.0",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.3",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "cacheDirectory": "./cache",
        "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
          "./app/utils/vendor"
        ],
        "coverageThreshold": {
          "global": {
            "statements": 80
          }
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "/node_modules/(?!react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|react-navigation|native-base-shoutem-theme|@shoutem/animation|@shoutem/ui|tcomb-form-native)"
        ]
      }
```

Here is my App-test.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import SomeComponent from '../components/Map';
jest.mock('react-native-google-signin', () => {
  return {
    statusCodes: {
      SIGN_IN_CANCELLED: '',
      IN_PROGRESS: '',
      PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE: '',
    },
  };
});

describe('Some component', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<SomeComponent />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The error shows up on any file i am trying to test.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Quite an old discussion but this may be of help: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/604

Comment: I unfortunately already tried this solution... Doesn't work for me. Thank you for your anwser, it may be useful to others.